# Facing latency issue in Azure EventHub consumer

Tags: .net-core, azure-eventhub, azure-sdk-.net, azure-eventhub-client

How to avoid latency in EventHub consumer data ? 
My Architecture (data flow): IOTHub -> EventHub -> BlobStorage (No deviation from IOTHub packet to Blob Storage JSON packet)
Deviation occurs only on consumer application side (Listener is receiving with delay of 30-50 seconds)

```
Azure Configuration: 4 Partitions with standard S2 tier subscription.
Publisher: 3000 packets per minute.
```

My question: BlobStorage has proper data without deviation, but why listener part is receiving with latency. How could I overcome this ?

Tried with EventProcessorClient with respective handlers as suggested in GitHub sample code. Works fine without error. But having huge latency.Tried EventHubProducerClient as well. still same latency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to how IoT Hub manages data internally or what it's expected latency between IoT data being received and when IoT Hub itself publishes to Event Hubs.

With respect to Event Hubs, you should expect to see individual events with varying degrees of end-to-end latency.  Event Hubs is optimized for throughput (the number of events that flow through the system) and not for the latency of an individual event (the amount of time it takes for it to flow from publisher to consumer).

What I'd suggest monitoring is the backlog of events available to be read in a partition.  If there are ample events already available in the partition and you’re not seeing them flow consistently through the processor as fast as you’re able to process them, that’s something we should look to tune.

## Additional Event Hubs context

When an event is published - by IoT Hub or another producer - the operation completes when the service acknowledged receipt of the event.  At this point, the service has not yet committed the event to a partition, and it is not available to be read.  The time that it takes for an event to be available for reading varies and has no SLA associated with it.  Most often, it’s milliseconds but can be several seconds in some scenarios – for example, if a partition is moving between nodes.

Another thing to keep in mind is that networks are inherently unreliable.   The Event Hubs consumer types, including `EventProcessorClient`, are resilient to intermittent failures and will retry or recover, which will sometimes entail creating a new connection, opening a new link, performing authorization, and positioning the reader.  This is also the case when scaling up/down and partition ownership is moving around.  That process may take a bit of time and varies depending on the environment.

Finally, it's important to note that overall throughput is also limited by the time that it takes for you to process events.  For a given partition, your handler is invoked and the processor will wait for it to complete before it sends any more events for that partition.  If it takes 30 seconds for your application to process an event, that partition will only see 2 events per minute flow through.